# crudGetList action does not delete from state data not present in response

Tags: react-redux, react-admin

**WARNING: This question is specific to react-admin framework**

I'm trying to do an in app manual, that uses data from server to load content pages. To doing so I'm doing a custom page that fetches manual pages on componentDidMount. In this function I call react-admin **crudGetList(*resourceName*, *pagination*, *sortingById*, *filters*)**, where filters is `{and:[{condition},{language: currentLanguage}]}` since I want to have the manual in different languages. I noticed that having pages in different languages in database and using crudGetList action with filters fetches the correct instances, however the state maintains old data. For example if I initially fetch data in English language, change language and go back to manual page, redux state will have pages for both languages instead of the current selected one.

Is this expected behaviour? Making the new request for manual pages shouldn't replace redux-state data to data coming from request? If is not expected should I open an issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React-admin uses a pattern called *optimistic rendering*. That means that if the app has fetched some entities in the past, if it needs to display these entities, it first shows the stale entities, then fetches the backend, and if the response differs, re-render the screen with up to date data.

For instance, when a user fetches a list of posts, react-admin stores these posts in a dictionary indexed by id:

```js
{
   123: { id: 123, title: "hello" },
   456: { id: 456, title: "world" },
   ...
}
```

React-admin also stores the list of identifiers that the list should display:

```js
[123, 456, ...]
```

Using these two properties, react-admin can now display the list. But it can also display the detail of a post without hitting the server first. So when a user clicks on an item in the list, react-admin uses the data from the first structure to display it right away, without waiting for the server response.

The purpose of optimistic rendering is performance: since the user doesn't need to wait for a round trip with the server, the interface is super snappy.

In your particular case, I understand that this can cause problems, because the store contains stale data that is not in the desired language. I suggest that you create a custom saga, which reacts to the language change action, and clears the store to avoid this kind of problem.

Check the documentation for custom sagas in the react-admin site:

https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Admin.html#customsagas

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure how the redux store responds to new incoming data.

More specifically, this is what a "reducer" is for; your "action" (in your case `crudGetList`) feeds the data into the "reducer", which is just a function with instructions to the store on how it should adjust its shape based on the new data.

Somewhere in your app there's probably a reducer that responds to your fetch action, but it's configured to just shove the new results alongside the old, rather than replace them. It's very difficult to know, however, without seeing the code describing the entire redux "cycle".

The redux docs are excellent. I'd start there and make sure you have a good understanding if the entire flow of data through redux, and then go hunting for that reducer.

https://redux.js.org/basics/reducers

Comment: I know how redux works, that is the reducer responsibility to change the state in response to an action, this is a problem because [this reducer](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/master/packages/ra-core/src/reducer/admin/resource/data.js) is managed internally by react-admin. A `RA/CRUD_GET_LIST` action is performed, but I have no control over it, is managed by the framework. I wanted to know from React-Admin team if this is expected behaviour, before open an issue.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. My sincere apologies; I didn't realize the question was specific to a "react-admin" library, and I assumed it was all internal to your app. Best of luck!

Comment: No need to apology, I forgot that using react-redux tag would add it to the respective stackoverflow filter. It was used to restrict question areas. Good that you were mislead, because it improved my question. Keep the good work!